# SWT confusion about events triggered on a TextField by CR/Return

Tags: event-handling, swt

I am fairly new to SWT and found that pressing "Return" on a TextField does (at least) three things: create an event for SWT.KeyUp, some microseconds later, an event for SWT.Dispose, and, SWT.DefaultSelection, the later two with (accidentally?) the same timestamp.

I mistakenly thought this would be only one event, being consumed by the first handler that received it.

Now my KeyUp-event is received by a Listener that is not intended to get it, as what should happen is already handled via the dispose and default handlers.

Question is: how to detect such situations and tell the Listener watching for "Return" to ignore this event?

---

I have finally found the cause, which were really two:

firstly, I checked `event.character == SWT.CR` instead of `event.keyKode == SWT.CR`.

Second, in my SWT.DefaultSelection-listener I called dispose() on the text field. Naturally, the disposed Text-field didn't have focus any more and the SWT.KeyUp event loaded with the CR was received by a different widget that happened to have the focus (a TabFolder in my case).

It looks like the listeners are processed in the sequence order in which they are added to a widget, but I can't find reference it this is by chance, implementation dependent or by design.

Comment: You would only get SWT.Dispose if you are disposing of some control - if you are doing that you need to make sure you remove any listeners on the control. Generally all applicable events are always sent - for Text KeyDown, KeyUp, Modify, DefaultSelection for Enter, ....

Comment: @greg-449 "only get SWT.Dispose if you are disposing of some control" ... I'd think so, but as it is, those part of the code has debug statements that are never run. Looks like the Dispose is triggered by "Return" on the TextField. Would make some sense?

Comment: If the text is in a dialog pressing return may cause the dialog to close and dispose the controls giving the Dispose event. Using a Traverse listener can stop that.

Comment: @greg-449 your first part is plausible and matches my observations, but how would a traverse listener, yet another listener, stop the events getting to the other listeners some of which are not under my control?

Comment: Traversal event are propogated up through the parent controls. A Traverse listener can prevent that happening. Events have a `doit` flag which can stop further processing of the event - exactly what that means depends on the event.

Comment: Note: For a Text control I would normally expect to use only the Modify, Verify and maybe Traverse listeners. I don't have any code using key up/down on text. It is also generally easier to create all the controls and use the layout to hide the ones that are inactive rather than disposing of them.

Comment: @greg-449 I know about the event.doit and set it to false as soon as I see it. The user should be able to press Return when on a Label to open a Text input in order to create a new element in the database. The Label cannot have focus, so I'm using the TabFolder it is embedded in to catch it. It works, with the bitter exception that a Return on the Text creates a selection-event, a dispose-event and still reaches my TabFolder making my application stutter. Worse, the CR-event I see has widget==TabFolder. I'm severely confused.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a Return in a `Text` field being processed use a traverse listener on the text:

```java
Text text = ....

text.addListener(SWT.Traverse, event ->
 {
    if (event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN)
      event.doit = false;
 });
```

Comment: Doesn't work, at least not out of the box. I'll have to do some debugging.; which is somehow hindered by https://stackoverflow.com/q/77631904/4142984 . Bad things come in triples, they say.

Comment: Your code is executed, including doit=false, but does not prevent the original CR-event from being processed. Different event.

Comment: Well you wil make to post a proper [mre] showing a reproducible example. I am not going to do any more guessing. The traverse code I show is from some of my code and works fine for me.

Comment: The code is quite large and to get a minimal reproducible example will take quite some time ... which is part of the problem. Worse, shortly I got everything working OK *once* by catching the CR with widget instanceof Text, but after dismateling all the debug and trace statements it didn't work again.  No way, I'll have do it the hard way and have to have a copy of the project and step by step strip it to the bones.